# QGIS processing won't save output to Geopackages

Tags: qgis

When running tools from the processing Toolbox I can save to shapefile etc but not to a geopackage as I get an error:

```
Could not create layer ogr:dbname='C:/GIS/Topo.gpkg' table="output" (geom): 
Loading of layer failed
```

Why? And how can I fix it?

```
QGIS version
3.30.3-'s-Hertogenbosch
QGIS code revision
2411cec1
Qt version
5.15.3
Python version
3.9.5
GDAL/OGR version
3.7.0
PROJ version
9.2.0
EPSG Registry database version
v10.082 (2023-02-06)
GEOS version
3.11.2-CAPI-1.17.2
SQLite version
3.41.1
PDAL version
2.5.3
PostgreSQL client version
unknown
SpatiaLite version
5.0.1
QWT version
6.1.6
QScintilla2 version
2.13.1
OS version
Windows 10 Version 2009




Active Python plugins
layoutnames
1.0
nominatim
1.4.5
db_manager
0.1.20
grassprovider
2.12.99
MetaSearch
0.3.6
processing
2.12.99
```

Comment: I can't reproduce. Outputting to gpkg works for me.